# Logarithmic axis for datetime not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot with Python/matplotlib in such a way, that the x axis (in datetime format) is scaled logarithmically.

With the code below, I could get a logarithmic y axis, but the logarithmic x axis does not work. What do I have to do that the logarithmic x axis works, too?

```
import pandas as pd

my_array = ["01.01.1990 23:59:12","01.01.1992 23:59:12","01.01.1994 23:59:12","01.01.1996 23:59:12","01.01.1998 23:59:12"]
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["a"]=[1,2,3,4,5]
df["my_date"] = pd.to_datetime(my_array, format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
df.index = df.my_date
df.drop(["my_date"],axis=1,inplace=True)
print(df)

                      a
my_date
1990-01-01 23:59:12  1
1992-01-01 23:59:12  2
1994-01-01 23:59:12  3
1996-01-01 23:59:12  4
1998-01-01 23:59:12  5

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.semilogx(df, "-o", markersize=2)
plt.show()
plt.semilogy(df, "-o", markersize=2)
plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You want to log transform a span of 8 years?

Comment: Yes, I know, that my desire is not so usual. But indeed, this is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The Pandas syntax is just

```
df.plot(logy=True, logx=True)
```

But you'll need a little distance in your dates to get a log-transformed axis to start looking like normal "loggy" graph.  You can still transform the year integer values to their log equivalents, but they'll just be smaller numbers very close together.  The x-axis will still have more-or-less linear ticks.

You can observe this by actually taking the log of the years of `my_date`:

```
np.log(df.my_date.dt.year)

0    7.595890
1    7.596894
2    7.597898
3    7.598900
4    7.599902
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your analysis. But I think that the x axis is still linear. At least the distance between 1907 and 1927 (and so on) is the same all over the axis up to 1987 (the `7x10^5` looks maybe like a bug in matplotlib... :-) ).

Comment: You're right!  I didn't look carefully enough.  I'll remove the counterexample.  But I think the point about transforming the years is still useful to call out here.  Maybe it would be helpful to know: What kind of graph are you expecting to see?